# Delete All query won't do anything upon clicking button (Room Database)

Tags: android, database, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to clear all entries in a table but the button linked with the SQL query through Room Persistence Library doesn't do anything. I have another button to add entries to the table and it works fine, I can't find any difference why clearing is not responding.

This is my DAO:

```
package com.jwanhsulaiman.talktag.database

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*

@Dao
interface VocabDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(vocab: Vocab) : Long

    @Update
    suspend fun update(vocab: Vocab) : Int

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(vocab: Vocab) : Int

    /**
    @Query("SELECT * from vocabulary_ah_types WHERE wordID = :key")
    suspend fun get(key: Long): Vocab?
    **/

    @Query("DELETE FROM vocabulary_ah_types")
    suspend fun deleteAll() : Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM vocabulary_ah_types ORDER BY wordID DESC")
    fun getAllVocabs(): LiveData<List<Vocab>>
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.jwanhsulaiman.talktag.database

class VocabRepository(private val dao : VocabDao) {
    val vocabs = dao.getAllVocabs()

    suspend fun insert(vocab: Vocab) : Long {
        return dao.insert(vocab)
    }

    suspend fun update(vocab: Vocab) : Int {
        return dao.update(vocab)
    }

    suspend fun delete(vocab: Vocab) : Int {
        return dao.delete(vocab)
    }

    suspend fun deleteAll(): Int {
        return dao.deleteAll()
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
package com.jwanhsulaiman.talktag.ui.home

import androidx.databinding.Bindable
import androidx.databinding.Observable
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.jwanhsulaiman.talktag.database.Vocab
import com.jwanhsulaiman.talktag.database.VocabRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class HomeViewModel(private val repository: VocabRepository) : ViewModel(), Observable {

    private val _text = MutableLiveData<String>().apply {
        value = "This is home Fragment"
    }
    val text: LiveData<String> = _text

    val vocabs = repository.vocabs

    @Bindable
    val inputVocab = MutableLiveData<String>()

    @Bindable
    val tagAll = MutableLiveData<String>()

    @Bindable
    val deleteAll = MutableLiveData<String>()



    init {
        tagAll.value = "Tag!"
    }

    fun tagAll(){
        val vocab : String = inputVocab.value!!
        insert(Vocab(0, vocab))
        inputVocab.value = null
    }

    fun insert(vocab: Vocab) : Job = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(vocab)
    }

    fun update(vocab: Vocab) : Job = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.update(vocab)
    }

    fun delete(vocab: Vocab) : Job = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.delete(vocab)
    }

    fun deleteAll() = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.deleteAll()
    }

    override fun addOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback?) {
        //TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(callback: Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback?) {
        //TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }


}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I think the query should be like "Delete * from ..." . you are missing *

Comment: @sak I thought that too but in all examples on the internet it was without * as I saw. I'm going to try it though!

Comment: @Jouan try by changing the return type to Long instead of Int.

Comment: @HimanshuDudhat changing to Long gives me Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'... anyway, weird, the problem solved itself with time, it works now

Answer (score 1):

deleteAll() function don't not return anything (void,Unit):

```
@Query("DELETE FROM vocabulary_ah_types")
suspend fun deleteAll()
```

instead of:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM vocabulary_ah_types")
suspend fun deleteAll() : Int
```

if that doesn't work can u show how you call it from ui

Comment: Thank you! After some time it worked with and without return type, I'm not sure what the problem was

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to implement a ViewModel, Repository, and DAO using the Room Persistence Library in Android. I'll provide some suggestions to troubleshoot and potentially fix the issue with the deleteAll functionality.

**1. ViewModel:**

- In the ViewModel, make sure that the method `deleteAll` in `HomeViewModel` is called when the button is clicked. You might want to check if there are any log statements or breakpoints to confirm whether the function is invoked.

**2. XML Layout:**

- If you are using data binding or listeners in your XML layout for the button associated with the `deleteAll` method, ensure that it is correctly set up. For example, if you are using `android:onClick` attribute, make sure it corresponds to the correct method in your ViewModel.

**3. LiveData Observers:**

- Ensure that you have an observer for the `vocabs` LiveData in your UI (e.g., in your Fragment or Activity). If the observer is not set up correctly, changes in the database won't be reflected in the UI.

Here's an example of how you might observe the `vocabs` LiveData in a Fragment:

```
class YourFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // Observe changes in the vocabs LiveData
    viewModel.vocabs.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { vocabs ->
        // Update your UI with the new list of vocabs
        // For example, you might update a RecyclerView adapter here
    })
}
```

}

**4. Error Handling:**

- Add some error handling in your ViewModel to see if there are any exceptions being thrown during the deleteAll operation. You can print logs or use a debugger to check for any issues.

**5. Check Repository:**

- Ensure that the `deleteAll` method in your `VocabRepository` is being called and is functioning correctly. You might want to add logs or breakpoints in that method.

After checking these points, you should be able to identify where the issue is occurring. If the problem persists, you might want to provide more details about how your UI is set up and how the deleteAll method is triggered.